# Definition for "string" in C

Tags: c, string, int

Correct me if I am wrong but the notation "C string" refers to a pointer that points to 3 or more bytes in memory, while the 3rd one is NULL.

---

Pointer must be at least 4 bytes in memory (since the address value they represent is similar to the integer, which is most likely stored in 4 bytes). Which means one pointer can point to an offset address without overflow, while according to the data type, n number of bytes will be readed. If it is `char` it is only the offset address to be readed. So if we allocate 6 bytes to `int*` we can have up to 2 characters without oferflow.

---

If the above said and rephrased by me is correct. Then:

```
int* str = calloc(sizeof(int), 2);
```

is a string that can contain up to 4 characters.
If we want to treat bytes separately we can use type-casting. Type-casting to ignore the warnings as well. Everything other then that, seems exactly like a string. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Where did you get the idea that a string must be at least 3 bytes long?  And how long the string in your example can be is dependent on what `sizeof(int)` is.

Comment: No, a C string is a chunk of memory that contains characters other than NUL, and terminated with a NUL character. The position of the NUL character determines the length of the string, so the empty string takes up exactly one byte, taken by the terminator itself. This kind of stuff is covered by any introductory book on C.

Comment: That's true.. but `sizeof(int)` assumes 4 bytes in this objective example. About my insight. Because string of one character is pointless, second character and the 3rd if it counts for the null-terminator.

Comment: @user4815162342 Actually the NULL determines where the strign ends not what is the length of it. Check `strlen`.

Comment: A 1-char string is not pointless at all. I can code a "string" of any length I like. It has nothing to do with the size of `int` on the machine, nor anything to do with indexing. I don't know where you got all your assumptions, but most of them are wrong.

Comment: @AlanSalios The two are interchangeable. `strlen` calculates the length by looking for the terminator NUL character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"String" is not really a data type of the C language at all. It is merely one way to *interpret* a sequence of bytes in memory. If a variable of type `char *` points to a certain piece of memory, and that memory contains a sequence of bytes ending with a byte of zero, then various library functions useful for minimal string handling will work with that pointer. How the memory got allocated, how big it is, what the nonzero bytes are, doesn't matter.

Comment: Well then I was right. You just confirmed that int buffer could be a string too.

Comment: Of course. If you allocate memory for an int (typically 4 bytes), nothing prevents you from using that memory to hold s string of three characters or fewer (one being needed for the zero byte).

Comment: Well that is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 8):

A C-string is simply the conventional term for a `nul` terminated memory buffer of `char` data types, which the C standard library functions regularly make use of.

A C-string can even be zero length, which would be a single `nul` terminator byte.

```
const char* s = "abc"; // C-string of length 3 pointing to a static string literal

char c = 0;
char* s = &c; // zero length C-string.

char s[] = "abc"; // C-string of length 3 allocated on the stack.

   // Another C-string of length 3 allocated on the stack
   // The brace initializer syntax explicitly shows the null terminator.
   //
    char s[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', '\0' };
```

That's really it.  A C-string is simply an array or memory buffer containing `char` data whose length is determined by the first occurrence of a `'\0'` char.  The size of a pointer has absolutely nothing to do with it.

Comment: How can I simply agree, since everything is stored as a number in memory. It is just interpreted as a char, which only finds a way of how to represent these values..

Comment: It's interpreted as a char because the C type system says it's a char.  We're not programming in BCPL anymore

Comment: So what? I can manually interpret buffer of int as buffer of 4 times more chars.. I am not interested of how bytes one string can be. It could be of any size.. if we take it literally. My real question is.. why we can not name ints as a string.

Comment: You can do whatever you want, Alan.  Everyone else is just following the conventions of the C standard.  If you'd rather do something else, go ahead, but please don't make me work on your code.

Comment: @AlanSalios Not with any degree of portability you can't. But yes, it's true that C allows type puning with wild abandon if that's what you want to do. It's a very powerful language, and like all powerful tools, you can hurt yourself badly by misusing it.

Comment: @Charles Salvia But I don't. I was just looking for a more appropriate difference between int and char as a buffer.

Comment: The difference between int and char is the size guarantee and the fact that the C type system treats them differently.  `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be 1, whereas `sizeof(int)` is not guaranteed to be a specific size.  (It is usually 4 on most 64-bit machines these days).  Plus there are no C standard lib functions which will interpret a null value (0) in an int array as anything special

Comment: @AlanSalios The most glaring difference occurs when you try to increment a pointer through that buffer. If your string is actually a pointer to `int`, all arithmetic operations on that pointer will be wrong.

Comment: @CharlesSalvia `char` could be also 2 bytes actually.
@CareyGregory Pointer arithmetic? Well that is avoidable too. WIth one thing and the same.. type-casting.

Comment: @AlanSalios The first words of your question are "Correct me if I am wrong". It doesn't appear you actually meant that.

Comment: If Lee Daniel Crocker can answer properly then it is obviously accurate enough.

Comment: @AlanSalios You got several correct answers plus a number of comments pointing out your errors. You argued with all of them, and you were incorrect. Now you claim your question was a good one because yet another person answered it. Your question earned 4 downvotes and I'm afraid it deserved every one of them.

Comment: Since when the people who answer a question decide whether the answer is good and/or answers the question ? I will argue until it is neccessary or until I am able to.

Comment: @AlanSalios Since forever. Look at the votes on the answers. That is the community telling you who has the best answer. Your acceptance of an answer only tells us that one person liked it.

Comment: People prefer well formated answers like that one than a deep one that actually answers with straight or potentionally straight information.

Comment: @AlanSalios `char could be also 2 bytes actually`  No it can't.  In 'C', sizeof(char) is *always* 1.  C is not Java.

Answer (score 1):

A string does not exist in C. C simply has character arrays that end in a null character.  The name of the char array is a pointer to the first char in the array. When you attempt to print a char array, you pass printf (or whatever you are using to print) the name of the char array and it will continue to print each char until it encounters a null character, at which point it will stop. There are no size restrictions on what makes a "string" a string.

Your example creates a pointer to int, which is not what you want. If you want to simulate a string in other languages, you need to create a pointer to char.

Comment: The C standard does use the term "string" to refer to a null-terminated array of char, so your first sentence (and the scare quotes around *string* later) is incorrect.

Comment: Change the words "encounter a null pointer" to "encounter a null character."

Answer (score 0):

```c
int* str = calloc(sizeof(int), 2);
```

This allocates space for two contiguous `ints` on the heap and returns a pointer to their location. It isn't in any way a string. How many `chars` you can pack into it depends on the size of `int` which varies across platforms, typically one of 16, 32, or 64 bits but it could be anything else greater than 16 bits.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question so should have been a comment.

Comment: @CareyGregory It corrects the incorrect assertion in the second half of the question.

Comment: Right, which makes it a comment, not an answer.